# binding datatable dynamically in angular2 not working

Tags: angular

I am using **Smart Admin Template** to display data in tabular format.

I tried to bind data with hard coded data it works but when i hit service.ts from component.ts on ngOnInit and set to the this.data. Although it sets but does not display to the ui/component.html.

Please see the code below. If any more help needed please let me know.

**1. Inside the component.html i have written :-**

```
    <sa-datatable ng-data="data" [options]="{
                colReorder: true,
                data: data,
                columns: [ {data: 'apiKey'}, {data: 'name'}]}"
                paginationLength="true" tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th data-hide="phone">APIKey</th>
                                        <th data-class="expand">
                                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user text-muted hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i>
                                            Name
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
</sa-datatable>
```

**2. Inside component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {JsonApiService} from "../shared/api/json-api.service";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Router, CanActivate }    from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'administration-apps',
    templateUrl: './administration.apps.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./administration.component.css'],
    providers: [JsonApiService]
})

export class AdministrationAppsComponent implements OnInit {
    //data = [{ "_id": "5807f24c762c48a0b548318f", "accountID": "580170af762c48a0b548318e", "name": "EZ FORMSTest 4", "active": true, "apiKey": "b2878c30-bea0-11e4-983f-d9ec76fdf276" }, { "_id": "580170af762c48a0b008318e", "accountID": "580170af762c48a0b54831ff", "name": "EZ FORMSTest 5", "__v": 0, "active": true, "apiKey": "b2878c30-bea0-11e4-983f-d9ec76fdf276" }];

    private data: any;
    private errorMessage: string;
    constructor(private jsonApiService: JsonApiService, private router: Router) {
    }
    createNewApp() {
        this.router.navigate(['/administration/apps/new'])
    }
  ngOnInit() {
      this.data = this.jsonApiService.getApps()
          .subscribe((apps: any) => { this.data = apps; console.log('looking for data now'); console.log(this.data);},
              error => this.errorMessage = error);
  }

}
```

**3. Inside json-api.service.ts**

```
getApps(): any {
  return this.httpGet('/app');
}
  httpGet(path) {
  let headers = new Headers({ 'X-TOKEN': '2f348e80-a26c-11e6-aea2-     b1b9938df75f' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  return this.http.get(this.baseURL + path, options)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .map(forms => {
          return forms;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to bind the Datatable by getting response from the API.

component was loaded earlier than getting api response data.

For that i **loaded  component at runtime.**

To load component dynamically these are few steps:-

**1. Create Dynamic Component dynamic.component.ts**

```
   import {Component, Input, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild, ReflectiveInjector,           
   ComponentFactoryResolver} from '@angular/core';
   import {AdministrationAppsDatatableComponent} from         
  './administration.apps.datatable.component';

  @Component({
 selector: 'dynamic-component',
 entryComponents: [AdministrationAppsDatatableComponent], // Reference to the     
 components must be here in order to dynamically create them
 template: `<div #dynamicComponentContainer></div>`,
 })
 export class DynamicComponent {
 currentComponent = null;

 @ViewChild('dynamicComponentContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef })     
 dynamicComponentContainer: ViewContainerRef;

// component: Class for the component you want to create
// inputs: An object with key/value pairs mapped to input name/input value
@Input() set componentData(data: { component: any, inputs: any }) {
    if (!data) {
        return;
    }

     // Inputs need to be in the following format to be resolved properly
    let inputProviders = Object.keys(data.inputs).map((inputName) => { return { provide: inputName, useValue: data.inputs[inputName] }; });
    let resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputProviders);

    // We create an injector out of the data we want to pass down and this components injector
    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedInputs, this.dynamicComponentContainer.parentInjector);

    // We create a factory out of the component we want to create
    let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(data.component);

    // We create the component using the factory and the injector
    let component = factory.create(injector);

    // We insert the component into the dom container
    this.dynamicComponentContainer.insert(component.hostView);

    // We can destroy the old component is we like by calling destroy
    if (this.currentComponent) {
        this.currentComponent.destroy();
    }

    this.currentComponent = component;
}

constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

}
}
```

**2. Created administration.apps.datatable.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Injector} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: "adminAppsHtml",
template: `<sa-datatable [options]="tblOptions"
                                      paginationLength="true"  
tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
                                      width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>APIKey</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </sa-datatable>

  `
  })

  export class AdministrationAppsDatatableComponent {
 tblOptions = {};
 constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    this.tblOptions = this.injector.get('options');
    console.log('looking for options in admin apps')
    console.log(this.tblOptions);
  }
}
```

**3. In component.html write like:-**
    where you want to display your datatable record.

```
<dynamic-component [componentData]="componentData"></dynamic-component>
```

**3 Include administration.apps.datatable.component inside the component where you are calling your API like in ngOnInit() method and in module also.**

```
import {AdministrationAppsDatatableComponent} from  
"./administration.apps.datatable.component";
ngOnInit() {
    this.jsonApiService.getApps()
      .subscribe((apps) => {          
      this.componentData = {
          component: AdministrationAppsDatatableComponent,
          inputs: {
              options: {
                  colReorder: false,
                  data: apps,
                  columns: [{ data: 'apiKey' }, { data: 'name' }]
              }
          }
      };
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = error);
```

}

To get running example please follow the link which i followed

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZXsIWykqKZi5r75VMtw2?p=preview